# The random variable $Y=F\left( X\right)$ is uniformly distributed on the interval $\left( 0,1\right)$

Tags: probability-distributions, continuity

This is a problem from "Probability: An Introduction", by Grimmett & Welsh, Problem 5.8.5. I am having some troubles in prove it, because I don't know if it can go straight out of the definition.

Let $X$ be a random variable whose distribution function $F$ is a continuous function. Show that the random variable $Y=F\left( X\right)$ is uniformly distributed on the interval $\left( 0,1\right)$.

The book sugests to call $F^{-1}\left(y \right) = \sup\left\{x: F\left(x \right) = y\right\}$, but I cant proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$F_Y(y)=\mathbb{P}[Y\leq y]=\mathbb{P}[F_X(x)\leq y]=\mathbb{P}[X\leq F_X^{-1}(y)]=F_X[F_X^{-1}(y)]=y$$

That's all!